# connect bluestacks with android studio on MAC

Tags: android-studio, bluestacks

on windows I am supposed to find adb.exe but on MAC I don't know where can I find such a file. I searched the web and didn't find any solution, is it possible at all?

Comment: Not a programming question.

Comment: i guess it would already be  removed

Comment: Consider asking on http://superuser.com

Comment: thanks in advance. What do you want jn return from me now?

Comment: I came here from google. Glad you opened this thread.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite simple it auto detects the BlueStacks as connect if it is on before you deploy the code.
Its detects it as Samsung SM-G900F for me in connected devices.
[What BlueStacks was detected as in mac](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANM19.png)

If you don't get this promte when you go to deploy your app make sure you have the setting target set to : "Open select target deployment target dialog"

[Target dialog setting in android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Adjjy.png)